# The alternative usage of fread

Tags: c++, loops, fread

I want to use *fread* or something similar in a strange way. I am not sure whether it is possible or not... Let me explain the case:

I have a *binary* file, named "*dummy*". This file contains unsigned char array in it. However, I want to take them into a float array which will store 4x memory space.

I can achieve my goal like the following:

```
FILE* in_file;
int numberOfCharacters = 1000; // number of unsigned characters to read ...
in_file = fopen("dummy", "rb");

float* floatArray = (float*) malloc( numberOfCharacters * sizeof(float) );

for(int i=0;i<numberOfCharacters;i++)
{
    unsigned char temp;
    fread(&temp, sizeof(unsigned char), 1, in_file);
    floatArray[i] = temp;
}
```

I know (actually didn't really try) this way will probably work. But I'm curious whether is there a better (faster) way of doing it? Maybe, without a loop..?

Thanks in advance,

Sait.

Comment: what's so strange? btw: to me it seems a C question

Comment: You may run into issues if the endianness doesn't match between the source of the binary file and the destination (where it is being read) and the writing/reading process doesn't take care of that.

Comment: The length of unsigned character array that I have is a little big. So, any improvement will be very helpful.

Comment: Also, possible dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422817/how-to-read-a-float-from-binary-file-in-c.

Comment: @dirkgently There is no endianness issue since he is reading `unsigned char`s and then casting them to `float`s.

Comment: @IronMensan: One-byte floats? That looks strange to me.

Comment: I'm very curious as to the reason you'd want to read in individual bytes & store them in an array as floats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example appears like it is okay (although some error checking might be good). One possible performance improvement might be to move the `fread` prior to the loop and read all 1000 entries at one time (into an allocated char array).  But that would probably be only slightly faster since fread is buffered.

Answer (score 1):

Off the cuff:

- You may run into issues if the endianness doesn't match between the source of the binary file and the destination (where it is being read) and the writing/reading process doesn't take care of that.
- Look up `setvbuf` to set buffering mode for your file.
- You may also want to look at memory-mapped files (`mmap`)
- This is much easier in C++ using `fstream` (file-streams) and iterators (i.e. syntactically). Further, if you want performance, you can create your own optimized file stream by overriding the appropriate members.
- For further reading look up [filtering streambufs](http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/att-49459/fltrsbf1.htm) too

Minor nits:

- In C, you don't need to cast the return value of `malloc`
- `#include` proper headers
- Test if `fopen` succeeded or not and then close the file once done
- Deallocate your `floatarray` once done

Answer (score 0):

Checking the returned value from fread for EOF will avoid extra looping and possibly filling the rest of floatArray with garbage

you can also get the size of the file with

```
fseek (in_file, 0, SEEK_END);
size=ftell (in_file);
```

If you want to allocate less memory for the float array